# Combine CSS Files - HTML5 Boilerplate Ant Build Script

Tags: html5boilerplate, build-script

I am using the latest version of H5BP along with their Ant Build Script and am having a hard time getting the CSS files to combine/concatenate when I run the build script. I am looking to combine the normalize.css and main.css into one file. I have tried adding the following to the project.properties file with no such luck:

```
file.stylesheets  = normalize.css
```

I have also tried:

```
file.stylesheets  = normalize.css,main.css
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to set

```
file.root.stylesheet    = normalize.css
```

then

```
file.stylesheets  = normalize.css,main.css
```

in project.properties